# How to write customizable functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-component

I am writing a reusable components first time for my project. This is a simple Dropdownlist component and that has several properties. I followed Revealing Prototype Pattern to implement this.

**This is my component.js and the html page that used DropdownList from component.js**

```js
   var Components = function(){

};

Components.prototype = function(){

 var guid = function () {
     return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
           s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
        };

        var s4 = function () {

          return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
            .toString(16)
            .substring(1);
 };

        var getDropDownList = function(){
          return new DropDownList();
 };

 var DropDownList = function(){
   this._id = guid();
 };

 DropDownList.prototype = function(){

   var data = [];
   var placeholderid = undefined;
   var selectedText = "";
   var selectedIndex = NaN;
   var defaultText = "";

   var setData = function(objArray){
    data = objArray;
    selectedIndex = 0;
   };
   var getData = function(){
    return data;
   };

   var addData = function(obj){
    data.push(obj);
   };

   var clearData = function(){
    data = [];
   };

   var setPlaceHolder = function(id){
    placeholderid = id;
   };

   var getPlaceHolder = function(){
    return placeholderid;
   };

   var setSelectedText = function(text){
    selectedText = text;
   };

   var getSelectedText = function(){
    return selectedText;
   };

   var setSelectedIndex = function(index){
    selectedIndex = index;
   };

   var getSelectedIndex = function(){
    return selectedIndex;
   };

   var setDefaultText = function(text){
    defaultText = text;
   };

   var getDefaultText = function(){
    return (defaultText == "" ? "Choose" : defaultText);
   };

   var onItemChange = function(onItemChangeCallback){
     
     //Append required html components to place holder
     $(`#${placeholderid}`).append(`<div class='dropdown' id=${this._id}><button class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' type='button' data-toggle='dropdown' name='dropdownButton'><span name='Selected-Text'>${getDefaultText()}&emsp;</span><span class='caret'></span></button><ul class='dropdown-menu'></ul></div>`);

     var mainComponent = document.getElementById(this._id);
     var itemContainer = $(mainComponent).find('ul');
     $(itemContainer).empty();

     if(data.length > 0){

      for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

       $(itemContainer).append(`<li><a>${data[i]}</a></li>`);// Add item to the list
       var currentAnchor = $(itemContainer).find('li')[i];

       /*Default on item click behavior*/
       $(currentAnchor).on('click',function(e){ // on list item click
        e.preventDefault();
        setSelectedText(data[i]); // set current selected data to selectedText property
        setSelectedIndex(i); // set current selected index to selectedText property
        $(mainComponent).children('button').eq(0).children('span').eq(0).prop('innerHTML',getSelectedText() + '&emsp;');//Set selected text to dropdownlist text


        /*Process user defined behavior*/
        onItemChangeCallback();
       });
       
      }
     }
     
    };

    /* Public properties and events of dropdownlist */
    return{
     getData: getData,
     setData:setData,
     addData : addData,
     clearData : clearData,
     getSelectedText : getSelectedText,
     getSelectedIndex : getSelectedIndex,
     setPlaceHolder : setPlaceHolder,
     getPlaceHolder : getPlaceHolder,
     onItemChange: onItemChange
    }
   }();

  return{
   getDropDownList : getDropDownList
  };
 }();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div id="place_holder_1">
      <!--Place holder to place dropdownlist-->
</div>
  


<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
     var components = new Components();

     var dummyArray = ["None","Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4","Item 5"];///Prepare Dummy Data

     var ddlTest = components.getDropDownList(); //get a new dropdownlist instance
  ddlTest.setData(dummyArray);//Set the data of the dropdownlist
  ddlTest.setPlaceHolder("place_holder_1");//Set a place holder for the dropdownlist

  ddlTest.onItemChange(function(){ 

      if(ddlTest.getSelectedText() === "Item 1"){
     alert("This is executed from user defined callback!");

      }
     
      console.log(ddlTest.getSelectedText());
                    console.log(ddlTest.getSelectedIndex());
     
        });
           });
 </script>
```

At my ***onItemChange()*** function of ***DropDownList.prototype***, it accept a function as parameter that to allow developers to implement their own code after the default behaviour of the component done.

**The question is**, Is this the right way to give customizable event of a component. Any suggestions are welcome on my code. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you creating your dropdown inside the `onItemChange` option? This way, if the user doesn't call `onItemChange` your dropdown is never created. Instead make an init function and put the logic to create your dropdown inside that function so the user can create the dropdown whenever they want by calling init.

Comment: Yes @Ozan you are right. Pretend that I changed the function name to init but I am still want to allow the developer to modify code when item select. So, I also added onItemChanged but the onclick event of item was attached inside init(). The problem is I don't know how to combine the onclick event with developer's new code from onItemChanged.

Comment: You simply create another property to handle the itemChange event. I partially edited your code to show what I mean, here: https://pastebin.com/AZ5yra5v.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ozan that's I want to know. Thank you.